# Nodejs http get and return statusCode

Tags: node.js, https

I want to run through a list of urls and check if they are valid if no 404 status code is returned. My code is as below. But `isValid` key in my data object doesn't seem to be populated accordingly.

```
var https = require('https');

const check = async url => {
  let result = false;
  try {
    const request = await https.get(url);
    result = request.statusCode !== 404;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return result;
};


// and in another function, I am doing this
const data = [];
const urls = [/* urls here */];
urls.forEach(url => {
 data.push({
   url,
   isValid: await isValidUrl(url)
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the different function, Use Promise.all to get data.

```
var https = require('https');

const check = async (url) => {
    let isValid = false;
    try {
        const request = await https.get(url);
        isValid = request.statusCode !== 404;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return {
        isValid,
        url
    };
};


// and in another function, I am doing this
const data = [];
const urls = [ /* urls here */ ];
const result = Promise.all(urls.map(url => check(url)))
```

Comment: if I will need to push in a different function as in my question, how would I do that? As there are extra keys in my object, isValid is just one of them that's getting its result from the check function